# Mobile/tablet optimization for HTML/CSS with MQ

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries, tablet

I'm stuck on a course assignment with the problem of optimizing my homepage for mobile and tablets in the correct way. The problem is I'm not even certain what questions to ask. I know my code doesn't fully work (I will provide it further down just in case) but the example code I'm given is very very strictly written  for a specific example, taken from my course literature. Hence I have huge problems applying it. I don't really now what to change and I've been trying for a month. Beginner programmer as you may understand.

I'm very sorry to ask such a vague question; this is rather an attempt to reach out to someone who has got the time to help me with my project. My teacher won't help me and I think I've read everything on Google by this point. I know I'm reaching.

Thank you in advance.

MQ code (if it does help):

```
/*MQ Mobile*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    html, body {    
     margin:0; /* remove default margin */
     padding:0; /* remove default padding */
     width: auto;
}
    #content { width: auto;}
    #text { width: auto;}
    main { margin-left: 0; width: auto; }
    aside {display: none; }
    nav li {display: inline-block; padding: 0.5em;}
    nav ul { text-align: center; }
    nav a { border-style: none;}
    h1 { font-size: 120%;}
    p {font-size: 90%}

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    html, body {    
     margin:0; /* remove default margin */
     padding:0; /* remove default padding */
     width: auto;
}
     h1 {font-size: 100%;}
     p { font-size: 120%; }
     figure { display: none; }
     nav, nav ul, nav li { padding: 0.1em; font-size:90%; }
     nav li {display: block;}
     nav a { display: block; padding: 0.5em 0; border-bottom: none;}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (min-width: 479px) and (max-width: 1024px){ /* your css between 1024px until for example 479px  */}
```

Comment: I don't understand. Where do you want me to put it? The first mq is made for tablets, the second for mobile usage.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.